# Best way to count downstream with edge data

Tags: graph, networkx

I have a NetworkX problem. I create a digraph with a pandas DataFrame and there is data that I set along the edge. I now need to count the # of unique sources for nodes descendants and access the edge attribute.

This is my code and it works for one node but I need to pass a lot of nodes to this and get unique counts.

```
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source="source", target="target", 
           edge_attr=["domain", "category"], create_using=nx.DiGraph)
downstream_nodes = list(nx.descendants(graph, node))
downstream_nodes.append(node)
subgraph = graph.subgraph(downstream_nodes).copy()

domain_sources = {}
for s, t, v in subgraph.edges(data=True):
    if v["domain"] in domain_sources:
        domain_sources[v["domain"]].append(s)
    else:
        domain_sources[v["domain"]] = [s]

down_count = {}
for k, v in domain_sources.items():
    down_count[k] = len(list(set(v)))
```

It works but, again, for one node the time is not a big deal but I'm feeding this routine at least 40 to 50 nodes. Is this the best way? Is there something else I can do that can group by an edge attribute and uniquely count the nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible enhancements:

1. Remove copy from line creating the sub graph. You are not changing anything and the copy is redundant.
2. Create a defaultdict with keys of set. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
import networkx as nx

# missing part of df creation

graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source="source", target="target", 
           edge_attr=["domain", "category"], create_using=nx.DiGraph)
downstream_nodes = list(nx.descendants(graph, node))
downstream_nodes.append(node)
subgraph = graph.subgraph(downstream_nodes)

domain_sources = defaultdict(set)
for s, t, v in subgraph.edges(data=True):
    domain_sources[v["domain"]].add(s)

down_count = {}
for k, v in domain_sources.items():
    down_count[k] = len(set(v))
```